# Windows Bridge for desktop does not finish process correctly

Tags: windows, uwp, installation, desktop-bridge

**Hi!**

This is not the duplicate of another question. I have attached the log. I have used the Windows Bridge ~2 years. I need an advanced answer. The StackOverflow has many talented windows developers even from Microsoft. Windows Bridge does not make a cleanup correctly and fails. It would be a bug in this technology.

**Hi!**

Could someone answer my question, please?
The Windows Bridge does not create a correct output.
It looks that it removes something from the folder, but it cannot.
I disabled the AV, the result is unsucceesful.
What would I do?

```
VERBOSE: An error occurred converting your application. Here is the full error record:
VERBOSE:

PowerShell Error Record:
Cannot remove item C:\DesktopAppConverter\21c0f04c-4eea-4f98-912b-9a47a3b0a91c\shared: Proces nie może uzyskać dostępu
do pliku „C:\DesktopAppConverter\21c0f04c-4eea-4f98-912b-9a47a3b0a91c\shared”, ponieważ jest on używany przez inny
proces.
PowerShell Stack Trace:
at Invoke-IsolatedInstall, C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util\IsolatedEnvironmentOps.ps1:
line 221
at <ScriptBlock><Process>, C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DesktopAppConverter.ps1: line 679
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1

Inner Exception[0]:
System.IO.IOException: Proces nie może uzyskać dostępu do pliku
„C:\DesktopAppConverter\21c0f04c-4eea-4f98-912b-9a47a3b0a91c\shared”, ponieważ jest on używany przez inny proces.
   w System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   w System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound, WIN32_FIND_DATA& data)
   w System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
   w Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.RemoveFileSystemItem(FileSystemInfo fileSystemInfo, Boolean
force)
Inner Exception Stack Trace[0]
   w System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   w System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound, WIN32_FIND_DATA& data)
   w System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
   w Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.RemoveFileSystemItem(FileSystemInfo fileSystemInfo, Boolean
force)
VERBOSE: The full error record is saved in the logs at C:\DesktopAppConverter\21c0f04c-4eea-4f98-912b-9a47a3b0a91c\logs
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 : Cannot
remove item C:\DesktopAppConverter\21c0f04c-4eea-4f98-912b-9a47a3b0a91c\shared: Proces nie może uzyskać dostępu do plik
u „C:\DesktopAppConverter\21c0f04c-4eea-4f98-912b-9a47a3b0a91c\shared”, ponieważ jest on używany przez inny proces.
At line:1 char:1
+ &'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.1.0_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DesktopAppConverter.ps1
```

*I highly appreciate the answer.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [desktopAppConverter Multiple MSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323538/desktopappconverter-multiple-msi-files)  
It is not the same question, but in the previous question you can find links to other free tools that can help with the conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. The DesktopAppConverter worked on my windows a few months ago. I do not need to change the platfom,

Comment: Can you clarify what you already tried to recover from this error? Have you tried using the -Cleanup option and setting up a fresh expanded image for conversion? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter#cleanup-params

Comment: I have cleaned all and reloaded the image. Problem exists. I do not remember, but the current image would be the first image installed on my Windows. While installing the image, script shows an error, that it has no NetNat as an error.

I have reported the problem, because the exception looks a bit like lower level error.

P. S. I have the latest stable Windows and Windows Image.

Comment: I am sorry for spamming. This is a blocking issue. I cannot add to Microsoft Store a new version of an app.
Would you help, please?

Comment: I found a way to fix this here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51437203/desktopappconverter-woes-windows-10-v-17134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a helpful contact with Microsoft I have decided to reinstall my OS.
Now everything works fine.