# DesktopAppConverter - PowerShell Error Record:Cannot remove item

Tags: powershell, inno-setup, desktop-app-converter

I am running DesktopAppConverter as an Administrator.

I have successfully downloaded and setup Windows_BaseImage_DAC_17134.wim

I am trying to package my app that has an Inno Setup installer program using veryslient mode.

**The command line instruction I am using is:**

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer C:\!DBLSetup\Output\DBL_Install.exe -InstallerArguments "/VERYSILENT" -Destination C:\!DBLPack\ -PackageName "DBLMoney" -Publisher "CN=DBLMoney" -Version 3.1.3.0 -Verbose
```

**I get the following error message.**

> PowerShell Error Record:Cannot remove item C:\DesktopAppConverter\423658cc-a23a-4a8d-9665-385e4a6d52d0\shared: The process cannot access the file 'C:\DesktopAppConverter\423658cc-a23a-4a8d-9665-385e4a6d52d0\shared' because it is being used by another process

C:\DesktopAppConverter\423658cc-a23a-4a8d-9665-385e4a6d52d0\shared\ is an empty folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [desktopAppConverter Multiple MSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323538/desktopappconverter-multiple-msi-files)

It is not the same question, but in the previous question you can find links to other free tools that can help with the conversion.